# how to auto scroll to a div in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i want my error message div to appear when i click on the submit button and i want that screen should auto scroll to that div my code snippet are below:

CSS:-
.error_msg

```
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F16200;
    border: 0 solid #FF1055;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 41%;
}
```

HTML of that div:

`<div id="error" class="error_msg">` Speed Link Successfuly Created for `{{display}}`

controller which is invoking on submit:-

```
tmeModuleApp.controller('speedLinksController',function($scope,APIServices,Paths,$rootScope) {
    $scope.setSpeedLink =function() {
        var setLink         = $('.active').attr('valset_link');
        var display         = $('.active').attr('valset_display');
        var display_name    = $('.active').attr('valset_link_name');
        if(setLink != '')
        {
            $location.hash('error');        
            $scope.display= display_name;           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out angulars [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24anchorScroll) service.

You should inject `$anchorScroll` and call it after `$locaiton.hash` call.

**Update**

*Example*

HTML

```
<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollCtrl">
  <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
  <a id="bottom"></a> You're at the bottom!
</div>
```

JS

```
function ScrollCtrl($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.gotoBottom = function (){
    // set the location.hash to the id of
    // the element you wish to scroll to.
    $location.hash('bottom');

    // call $anchorScroll()
    $anchorScroll();
  };
}
```

Comment: i should use both of these in that function which is on onclik right?

Comment: it says Unknown provider: locationProvider

Comment: @user3659806 Are you trying to inject location in ```module.config```? If so, you better to do it in ```module.run```

Comment: @user3659806 Updated answer with an example